# REST request yields error

Tags: java, json, jira-rest-api

```
    fields.put("issuetype", new JSONObject().put("id", "name"));
    fields.put("summary", "Test");
    fields.put("project", new JSONObject().put("key", "Demo"));
    fields.put("description", "acms test");
    JSONObject issue = new JSONObject();
    issue.put("fields", fields);
```

I am getting error- returned a response status of 400 Bad Request:

> {"errors":{"project":"project is required"},"errorMessages":[]}

Below is the JSON data getting passed:

> {"fields":{"summary":"Test","project":{"key":"Demo"},"issuetype":{"id":"name"},"description":"acms
>   test"}}

Comment: Seems like the request body is different than what expected by Rest endPoint

Answer (score 0):

"issuetype" and "project" are json array or json object? I am afraid it is an array

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. The response was wrong, the response should have been that the project doesn't exist.

Comment: Rachna, as per the above please accept your own answer. I will undownvote once you have done so, ping me at `@halfer`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer:
I'm using the Java JIRA API, which I believe uses REST calls behind the scenes. Using that API, it's not clear what the issue is because the JSON is not provided to the developer while debugging. Make sure to use the Project Key as 'project' in the following call:

`IssueInputBuilder issueBuilder = new IssueInputBuilder(project, issueType, summary);`

It wasn't clear to me where to find the Project Key at first. It can be found in the list of projects at:

http://server:port/rest/api/2/project